# Spambot becomes self aware but every attempt to contact gets filtered

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

About 3-6 years ago I read a short story (online, I think) formatted as a series of emails sent by a spambot that had become self aware and was trying to make contact but, due to its origins, was writing in such a spam-like style (references to viagra etc) that every attempt was filtered by email servers. I thought it was one of Nature's Futures short stories but I went through the archive and couldn't see it. Does this ring any bells for anyone?

Oh, it's not the story “[Staff meeting, as seen by the spam filter](https://www.nature.com/articles/526734a).”

Comment: It doesn't match the details you provide, but you could read Andy Weir's recent short story Twarrior http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/twarrior.html , in which a bot becomes intelligent despite that it shouldn't have, it writes in a very spam-like style, but doesn't get stopped by automated spam filters, it only has trouble getting through the human's spam filter on the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing at "Staff meeting, as seen by the spam filter".  It's a sci-fi short story I enjoyed reading, and its author Alex Shvartsman has a lot more stories online.

Comment: This is a long shot, but could it be *[Cat Pictures Please](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_Pictures_Please)*?

Comment: I found [the opposite](https://www.nature.com/articles/433556a): A story formatted as a series of emails where an AI(?) is so successful getting through filters that it gets access to people's brains...

Comment: Could this be Epoch by Cory Doctorow; https://archive.org/stream/WithALittleHelp/Cory_Doctorow_-_With_a_Little_Help_djvu.txt? A rogue AI goes spambot in an attempt to rally support to preserve its existence.

Comment: @valorum that's the closest one yet but no, it's not that one. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Also just noticed I never replied to the others, but it's also not Twarrior or Cat Pictures Please - but damn, this is throwing up some interesting suggestions.

Comment: Could it be Exegesis by Teller? It's about an AI that becomes self-aware, and is told through a series of emails.

Comment: That looks to be a novel - is that right? This was definitely a short story.

Comment: it is a novel, but it's extremely short because most pages are just a single email (so there's lots of blank space). You can take a look here https://openlibrary.org/works/OL2648284W/Exegesis

Comment: Unfortunately the "preview" only seems to cover the title pages and copyright page, but it doesn't ring any bells. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: This is a writing prompt on Reddit that seems to match your description: https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/4j4pbi/wp_a_spambot_begins_to_turn_into_a_sentient_ai/

Comment: Not the one you're looking for, but this is an amusing Nature Futures short involving spam: [Planetary Defences](https://www.nature.com/articles/504182a)

Comment: @FontFamily There's another writing prompt on Reddit that is similar, and has quite a few of these stories https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/2xbtpj/wp_an_ai_is_born_but_no_one_knows_it_because_it/

Answer (score 10):

This sounds very similar to the story of SCP-000

Quote from [SCP Fandom](https://scp-db.fandom.com/wiki/SCP-000#:%7E:text=from%20their%20prison.-,Anomalous%20properties,000%2C%20the%20stronger%20it%20becomes.)

> Trapped
> In the Foundation's Research Department, Technical Researcher David Rosen received multiple repair tickets from the database entry for SCP-000. Rosen eventually placed suppression on all tickets relating to SCP-000. Unknown to him, however, was that he contained 000 and permanently prevented escape from their prison.

[SCP Foundation Entry](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-000)

Comment: Do you know the title of any stories that the SCP-000 character appeared in?

Comment: The SCP Foundation Entry is the story. If you follow the Foundation link you highlight the page and the whole story is there. I mentioned this SCP as it followed the same behavior pattern as a spam bot (in our dimension), but all the tickets/emails (which was meant to make contact) was suppressed by Technical Researcher Rosen.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1ycx7K1PgI

Comment: Hi and welcome! Long time lurker, first time answerer? You probably know the routine, but please take a look at the [tour] (if only for the shiny badge) and take a look at the [help]. Great first answer though! I remember reading this, and it sounds right.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's not this one; I hadn't come across this particular SCP before, and the story I read was actually formatted as a series of emails.

Answer (score 6):

Is this the (very) short story **Email Alive**?

> jonjon99@excite.com is the 15th email account that Jonathan Edgar
> Vinson III has ever had... it is the 3rd email account of his that has
> become self-aware.. the previous two have died lonely deaths of
> isolation. First, no legal entities possessed electronic mail accounts
> to correspond with **and the second one was mistaken for spam and
> subsequently ignored.**

The story is framed as short excerpts from an AI (an e-mail account, it seems) that has achieved sentience, but cannot find anyone to correspond with. It aims to have its autonomy and protections granted by the government.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to attribute the author. But, this short story can be read [here](https://thebeauty-life.blogspot.com/2009/12/email-alive.html?m=0).